# ajax-jquery post, server ist not receiving any form data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I have a form with the id "#ajaxform". If I send an ajax request with the data as `formData = {id: 'something'};`, everything works fine and the server gets the data as POST. But if I send the ajax request with the data `formData = $(this).serialize();`, the server is not receiving any data.

See my ajax code below.

```
        $("#ajaxform").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
        // add loading image to div
        $('#ajaxchanger').html('<?php echo __('loading...'); ?>');
        //var formData = {id: 'something'}; // if I call the ajax with this data instead the next line, it works!
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        var formURL = $(this).attr("action");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "html",
            data: formData,
            processData: true,
            url: formURL,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                // replace div's content with returned data
                $('#ajaxchanger').html(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("An error occurred: " + jqXHR.responseText.message);
                console.log(jqXHR);
            }
        });
    });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try $("#ajaxform").serialize(); instead of $(this).serialize();

Also make sure, you need name attribute on your input fields. Otherwise they're ignored

Comment: Thanks, always the same problem. Every input field has a name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Becase `.serialize()` ***Encode a set of form elements as a string for submission***.  And By default $.ajax use `GET` datatype to submit your data. so lets say you have a string `name=yourname&email=youremail@example.com` and url is `//example.com/request_handler` Then your url become with `GET` method is:

```
http://example.com/request_handler?name=yourname&email=youremail@example.com
```

Which is working perfect according to GET METHOD.

For `POST` it is same because according to [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) documention its making **form element as string**. So `POST` datatype will not work with `.serialize()`. To debug more deply see the request in the browser console.

Comment: Thank you jogesh_pi. But do you know how I can send the Form Data as post data with the ajax request?

Comment: @FishWave Divide string into objects and sent it to the form like `data: {"name":yourname,"email":youremail@example.com}`

Comment: Yes, thank you. I had this idea. But I wish there was a more general solution for all the inputs in a form that the jquery code is usable for all my forms - not only for a specific.

Comment: @FishWave are you using PHP at sever side?

Comment: Yes. Serversided everything works fine if the server would receive post data.

Comment: @FishWave then why not use `parse_str()` to convert string as variable and valules? send throug ajax like `post: {data: formData}` and use from server end like `parse_str($_POST['data']);`

Answer (score 0):

The following line has a PHP error.

```
$('#ajaxchanger').html('<?php echo __('loading...'); ?>');
```

Change like

```
$('#ajaxchanger').html('<?php echo __("loading..."); ?>');
```

I tested the code and good results.

Use a "syntax aware" editor. You can avoid this kind of syntax error.

Comment: Yes, you are partially right. If I change the line, the problem is still there. But if I comment out the line, then everything works fine. Thank you!

Comment: Now, I got it! It was the line above as mentioned by k.abbey. The point is, in that moment, when I set the "loading...", the the form does no longer exist but the ajax have not fired yet. As a result, the ajax has no data because there is no form anymore...